# WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies

Tags: grails, jboss, dependencies, wildfly, web-deployment

We are new to Groovy / Grails development, and are attempting to upgrade a legacy application to JRE 1.8. We upgraded from Grails 1.3 to Grails 2.5.6, and were able to resolve all dependency errors and build the WAR file. When deploying the WAR file to WildFly 14 the log shows the following errors. What does this mean? Do we need to add something to the `BuildConfig.groovy` file or change something in the WildFly configuration or something else? Thanks!

```
11:36:01,111 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.8.6.Final
11:36:01,599 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.3.Final
11:36:01,614 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.2.Final
11:36:01,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 14.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final) starting
11:36:02,854 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.6.0.Final
11:36:03,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
11:36:04,068 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
11:36:04,099 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.6.5.Final
11:36:04,115 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.6.5.Final
11:36:04,224 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
11:36:04,365 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.11.Final)
11:36:04,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
11:36:04,380 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
11:36:04,396 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.6.1.Final
11:36:04,396 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
11:36:04,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
11:36:04,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
11:36:04,443 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final
11:36:04,443 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
11:36:04,458 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
11:36:04,458 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:36:04,474 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
11:36:04,474 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
11:36:04,474 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
11:36:04,490 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.13.Final starting
11:36:04,490 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
11:36:04,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
11:36:04,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:36:04,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:36:04,818 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) AMQ222269: Please use a fixed value for "journal-pool-files". Default changed per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1628
11:36:04,818 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) AMQ221075: Usage of wildcardRoutingEnabled configuration property is deprecated, please use wildCardConfiguration.enabled instead
11:36:04,818 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
11:36:05,237 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
11:36:05,245 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
11:36:05,246 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
11:36:05,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
11:36:05,491 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
11:36:05,491 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.8.Final
11:36:05,507 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
11:36:05,554 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
11:36:05,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\deployments
11:36:05,616 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
11:36:05,679 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
11:36:05,741 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
11:36:05,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:36:05,850 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.5.jbossorg-1) 
11:36:06,100 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
11:36:06,200 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\largemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\data\activemq\paging)
11:36:06,312 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
11:36:06,469 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 238,813,184
11:36:06,531 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
11:36:06,531 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
11:36:06,531 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
11:36:06,531 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
11:36:06,672 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
11:36:06,672 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
11:36:07,587 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
11:36:07,587 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
11:36:07,587 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
11:36:07,587 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
11:36:08,009 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221007: Server is now live
11:36:08,009 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.6.3.jbossorg-001 [default, nodeID=37ac2577-e762-11e8-8a37-0028f82006ed] 
11:36:08,009 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
11:36:08,071 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMSGAMQ0006: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
11:36:08,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
11:36:08,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0011: Unbound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
11:36:08,167 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
11:36:08,201 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-5) AMQ151007: Resource adaptor started
11:36:08,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-5) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
11:36:08,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
11:36:08,207 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
11:36:08,298 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
11:36:08,298 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
11:36:08,298 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:36:08,298 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 14.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final) started in 7630ms - Started 342 of 565 services (337 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:39:19,044 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location C:\wildfly-14.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content\9c\a9f7064345fb10bcfb389af6732862fb882c3c\content
11:39:19,059 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war" (runtime-name: "myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war")
11:39:29,486 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in /C:/wildfly-14.0.1.Final/bin/content/myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.2.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
11:39:31,767 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:39:31,767 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
11:39:31,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
11:39:31,955 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-8) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Estrella Galicia' 9.3.1.Final
11:39:32,001 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war_org.h2.Driver_1_3
11:39:32,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
11:39:32,283 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war")]) - failure description: {
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.myproj_admin"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war\".undertow-deployment is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server.myproj_admin]",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server.myproj_admin]"
]}
11:39:32,298 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.myproj_admin"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war\".undertow-deployment is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server.myproj_admin]",
    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war\".undertow-deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server.myproj_admin]"    ]}
11:39:32,314 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war_org.h2.Driver_1_3
11:39:35,577 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war (runtime-name: myprojAdminTool-1.02.01.war) in 3293ms
11:40:09,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0236: Suspending server with no timeout.
11:40:09,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
11:40:09,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Management Triggered Shutdown) WFLYSRV0241: Shutting down in response to management operation 'shutdown'
11:40:09,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
11:40:09,576 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0006: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
11:40:09,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
11:40:09,592 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
11:40:09,592 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0011: Unbound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
11:40:09,592 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 142) WFLYMSGAMQ0006: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
11:40:09,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
11:40:09,623 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 144) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
11:40:09,639 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 142) AMQ151003: resource adaptor stopped
11:40:09,764 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 142) AMQ221002: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.6.3.jbossorg-001 [37ac2577-e762-11e8-8a37-0028f82006ed] stopped, uptime 4 minutes
11:40:09,764 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
11:40:09,779 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
11:40:09,779 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.0.13.Final stopping
11:40:09,779 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 14.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final) stopped in 219ms
```

Comment: Is there any other error appearing at the log? This error only shows that the undertow ( the wildfly webserver) could not be started.

Comment: Updated post to include the full log, but there are no additional errors. The WildFly console site on port 9990 is working. The error actually occurs when we enable the deployed WAR.